# Any reason why SQL Server 2022 should not be installed on the same Windows 10 PC with SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql-server

Assuming they'd be named instances and listening on different ports, can SQL Server 2022 be installed on a Windows 10 PC that has SQL Server 2017 already on it?  [This Microsoft article from March 2023](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/work-with-multiple-versions-and-instances-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#using--side-by-side-with-previous-versions-of-) doesn't mention SQL Server 2022, so I figured it would be prudent to ask.

Comment: I am running SQL 2022 on a win 10 machine without any issues. Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU2) (KB5023127) - 16.0.4015.1 (X64) 
 Feb 27 2023 15:40:01 
 Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 19044: )

Comment: @SqlWorldWide Thanks, but did you have an earlier version of SQL Server installed on the machine before you installed V2022?

Comment: yes SQL2019. I still have another machine with windows 11, with both SQL 2019 and SQL 2022.